# SQL Server DDL trigger not firing

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a DDL trigger on CREATE_TABLE in the tempdb (yes, I know it will be wiped out when the server restarts) as:

```
use tempdb;
go

create trigger tt1
on database
for create_table
as
    begin
    print 'TRIGGER FIRED';
    raiserror('TEST ERROR', 16, 1);
    rollback;
    end
go

use master;
go

create table #ttt (f1 nvarchar(25));
select * from #ttt;
drop table #ttt;
```

...but the trigger does not appear to be firing.

Can anyone explain what I need to do to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to get this to work

> DDL triggers fire only after the DDL statements that trigger them are
>   run. DDL triggers cannot be used as INSTEAD OF triggers. **DDL triggers
>   do not fire in response to events that affect local or global
>   temporary tables and stored procedures.**

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2014)

Comment: Thanks! I saw some blogs showing triggers that claimed to operate on the tempdb.